# Scapy padding.load what is the meaning of 'g' and '|' symbols

Tags: python, hex, scapy

I append to tcp packet unsinged long long with value 4 and additional unsigned long long with value 8616616 ( i dont remember the second value ).
I do it in c on ubuntu 32 , so unsigned long long is 8 bytes.

I sniff the packet with scapy and print the padding.load .
In the output i see symbols that i dont undesrtand the meaning of them - g, |
In additional the load should be 16 bytes , but i dont see 16 bytes.

If i append only one unsigned long long i get 8 bytes and i dont see these symbols

```
>>> pkt = sniff(count=2,filter="tcp")
>>> raw  = pkt[1].sprintf('%Padding.load%')
>>> raw
"'\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00g\\xc4|\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'"


>>> print raw
'\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00g\xc4|\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are printing out the value of `raw`, python interprets all bytes that have a value greater than 31 as ASCII characters. When you see `g` the value for that byte is equal to 103, likewise `|` is the ASCII code for 124. For characters above 127, python uses a different representation which is why you have `\xc4` in your output, the value of that byte is 196.

The actual value of each of the bytes in `raw` is:

```
[4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 103, 196, 124, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Which is 16 bytes long.

You can test this by converting the value of each byte back into a character:

```
>>> values = [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 103, 196, 124, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> as_characters = ''.join(chr(c) for c in values)
>>> as_characters
'\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00g\xc4|\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> len(as_characters)
16
```

I think what you have for `raw` has had each of the bytes escaped. In my example, when I output `as_characters` I only see a single backslash, you have two. You may need to use something like `pkt[1].sprintf('%Padding.loadr%')` to get the non escaped version.

Comment: Thank you , is there a simple way to take 8 bytes and convert them to int ( need also to convert to big indian ) i know that unpack suppose to do this , but i dont know how to represent this as tuples of 8 hex

Comment: Take a look at using struct. `struct.unpack('b', my_byte)`. To do so for 8 would be `struct.unpack('8b', my_bytes)`.

Comment: You probably want `struct.unpack('2Q', raw)` which returns `(4, 8176743)`. `Q` is for `unsigned long long`.